# Bootstrap Datepicker, maxdate, 2 days from the first date selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Lets say for example that I make the first selection within Check-In on May 10th, it automatically goes to the Check-Out section with May 10th selected as well and rest of the days afterwards available. What I'm trying to do is make it so that the day selected and the following 2 days are available and not the rest.

If your curious about documentation, the URL link for the Bootstrap Datepicker that I'm using is: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

A JSFiddle link of what I currently have is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9f6xhrm9/2/

If the above JSFiddle link doesn't work for you, then its probably cause your browser is forcing a https, using chrome does not cause this issue except for when I make it into a https. So either switch to chrome or here is the files associated with the JSFiddle link - located below:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css

http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap.css

Though since it's required to have the associated code from JSFiddle on here, I posted that down below as well:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtCheckIn" placeholder="* Check-In Date (M/D/Y)" readonly>
<input type="text" id="txtCheckOut" placeholder="* Check-Out Date (M/D/Y)" readonly>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate()+7);
$('#txtCheckOut').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var checkin = $('#txtCheckIn').datepicker({onRender: function(date) {return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';}})
.on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        $('#txtCheckOut').removeAttr('disabled');
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide(); $('#txtCheckOut')[0].focus();
})
.data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#txtCheckOut').datepicker({onRender: function(date) {
    if (checkin.date.valueOf()) {return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';}
    else {return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';}
}})
.on('changeDate', function(ev) {checkout.hide();})
.data('datepicker');});
```

To help out, I know that part of the answer deals with using something like the following code:

```
date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ''
```

most likely to be put within this bit of code:

```
      if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        $('#txtCheckOut').removeAttr('disabled');
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
      }
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work, as your included assets from `http://www.eyecon.ro` return a `403:Forbidden` error. Please link these from a valid site, like `bootstrapcdn`

Comment: I'll just give the URL links for the pertinent css and js files on here in a few moments. Had a few friends test the JSFiddle link with the calendar, for some it worked and some it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the datepicker that you're using, I see that [eternicode's fork](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) is being actively maintained. I'm not sure what the differences are but [in the docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#enddate) eternicode's version is helpful.

The key is setting `startDate` and `endDate` in the options.

```
$(function () {
    var checkout = $('#txtCheckOut').datepicker();
    var checkin = $('#txtCheckIn').datepicker({
        startDate: "today"
    }).on('changeDate', function(event) {
        var newDate = new Date(event.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 2)
        checkout.datepicker("setStartDate", event.date);
        checkout.datepicker("setEndDate", newDate);
    });
});
```

See the working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/by2p9vxm/4/)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you wrote for the resources you're using, however the resources you chose aren't the same that I'm currently using. So all in I can't use what you posted up above, because it won't work with what I have.

Part of the answer to my problem is in using something like

> now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ' '

As for the rest of the code to use associated with it before the > I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: The reason I used something different was: 1. this is maintained and 2. I could actually link to it from jsfiddle. The eyecon version was last updated in 2013. You don't need most of the `valueOf` code you currently have because `startDate` and `endDate` do it automatically. I don't know what you are unable to get working...

Comment: Is the site valid? Yeah, they have more then one project going. Is my code broken and/or is JSFiddle link messed up? No, its the browser forcing a https when it's a http, use Chrome because it doesn't cause this issue in JSFiddle. As for the use of "valueOf" that was part of the original script from the example code from the Eyecon site, so you'd have to ask them. The use of startDate and endDate was added into the js file from Eternicode, which didn't originate in Eyecon. Your suggestion would make me redo all the other functions, when I only needed one thing added in 1-2 lines of code.

Comment: I am using Chrome. I didn't have the problem to begin with and then suddenly it started up and I got over it. Choosing to use an unmaintained library is not a wise decision though. That's why the fork was made and seriously, what other functions? Chances are good that a lot of the code still works and if you're willing to debug for five minutes you'd be able to fix it.

Comment: Looked into your versions of 0-2 in JSFiddle, V-0 has you using startDate, for the resources I'm using when those resources don't use startDate. That version doesn't have the https, its http, so the problem you came across is most likely from using code that the resources don't have. Though you're right, only took a few minutes to get most of the parts to work as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/by2p9vxm/3/  however Eternicode code for the "hide" part is bugged. Its supposed to hide the calendar popup, not the input area. You can add checkin.hide();  to see the bug.

Comment: you need to call the function in the "jQuery plugin way" `checkin.datepicker('hide')`. See http://jsfiddle.net/by2p9vxm/4/ (I've also added some css to position the picker more nicely)

Comment: Seems we came up with same/similar solutions. I looked through a bit of the documentation and found a autoclose, plus i added a few resources so that the calendar looks better too, along with using another bit that Eternicode has in their resource that i liked. http://jsfiddle.net/by2p9vxm/6/
 Thanks for the help, i'll upvote you're answer, i was just frustrated the past few days with the resource I had, though yeah Eternicode resource is quite a bit easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

With help from jcuenod, the solution is in the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/by2p9vxm/6/

While using Eternicode resources, the script for that is smoother and easier to deal with, along with a more comprehensive documentation, again thanks for the help jcuenod.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtCheckIn" placeholder="* Check-In Date (M/D/Y)" readonly>
<input type="text" id="txtCheckOut" placeholder="* Check-Out Date (M/D/Y)" readonly>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
var checkout = $('#txtCheckOut').datepicker({autoclose: true, format: 'M/dd/yy'});
$('#txtCheckOut').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var checkin = $('#txtCheckIn').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'M/dd/yy',
    startDate: "+7d"
}).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    $('#txtCheckOut').removeAttr('disabled');
    var newDate = new Date(event.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 2)
    checkout.datepicker("setStartDate", event.date);
    checkout.datepicker("setEndDate", newDate);
    $('#txtCheckOut')[0].focus();
});});
```